# Use PathInterpolatorCompat in XML to perform Android fragment custom animation?

Tags: android, xml, android-animation

I'm trying to use the `<pathInterpolator>` to create a custom fragment animation in Android. The app must support API 19 and above.

res/anim/slide_in.xml:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:interpolator="@anim/myinterpolator"
           android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0"
           android:duration="1000"/>
```

res/anim/myinterpolator.xml:

```
<pathInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:controlX1="0.33"
                  android:controlY1="0"
                  android:controlX2="0"
                  android:controlY2="1"/>
```

This works great on a device with API 21, but it crashes on an API 19 device because PathInterpolator was added in API 21.

I'd like to use [PathInterpolatorCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/animation/PathInterpolatorCompat.html) instead to support API 19, but how can I use it in XML?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, I can't understand why it is not possible to use it in xml...

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @abhiarora No, I never found a solution, but I gave up on this code years ago.